# Can I use two languages in a Heroku app?

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku

I want to use Node.js as a Share.js server and Ruby for the frontend. As far as I know, Heroku only allows one web-facing process called "web". Does anyone have some experience trying to do something like this?

Comment: I think (not an answer) that you will need a paid separate worker process to do this.

Comment: You can AFAIK only have one web process. You can have additional worker processes but they most likely would not be given a valid port to listen on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Heroku detects the application type when you push your code to Heroku and it compiles the slug. You'd need to have them as seperate applications with a defined API between the two (not always a bad thing)

UPDATE: You can 'stack' buildpacks these days, eg Ruby + PHP so you could have both executed. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app for how to use multiple buildpacks in the same app.

Comment: It is not always impossible, please see my answer before completely giving up.

Answer (score 3):

As a caveat, you technically can install two languages on a single app — but I'm not sure about running them concurrently. I made this buildpack to combine NodeJS and PHP (so that I could run Grunt during the slug compilation):

https://github.com/gcpantazis/heroku-buildpack-php-gruntjs

The language detection is usually fairly dumb; it'll be looking for a file indicative of the lang, i.e. index.php or a rakefile. You'll have to change the detect bin so that your code will pass.

**Update:**

Even better, consider using https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi ; it'll let you install buildpacks sequentially. Depending on your application you might need to find language buildpacks that don't have verification steps, i.e. checking for a `package.json` file in a NodeJS app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is *mostly* possible I believe, as long as you're not doing something very tricky. I once deployed a Flask (Python) app that used Stanford's CoreNLP - which is all written in Java. You will need [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).

After adding this, make sure to make a `.buildbacks` file and add all the buildpacks you will be needing from the [Heroku github](https://github.com/heroku/).

This circumvents Heroku detecting your app type itself and makes it install all necessary buildpacks from the `.buildpacks` file.

Comment: You don't need to use .buildpacks anymore - it's part of the platform these days, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app